# Which Star Trek TNG episode involves a planet fighting over territory and thus being unable to join the Federation?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

I think the premise was that the planet was technologically advanced enough to join the Federation, but with people fighting over territory, they weren't allowed to join until that was resolved.

I think it ends with Picard telling a fighting leader that they could be discovering the universe with them, but would rather fight over land. The leader says the Picard doesn't understand.

I'm probably getting the details wrong though; haven't seen it in awhile. And it's possible I'm mixing up more than one episode.

Comment: TNG The Hunted had a similar(ish) premise; http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/159.htm

Comment: I think that was the episode I was thinking of and mixed up parts with the attached lol

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're conflating two episodes; *[TNG: Attached](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attached)* and *[TNG: The Hunted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hunted_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation))*. Both revolve around planets that are in the midst of application for Federation membership.

---

[*TNG: Attached*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Attached_(episode)) focuses on a planet applying for Federation membership, Kesprytt.

> Captain's log, Stardate 47304.2. The Enterprise has arrived at Kesprytt III in order to evaluate an unusual request on the part of the Kes for associate membership in the Federation.

At the end of the episode Riker gives his evaluation of their chances (spoiler, not good)

> **RIKER:** *As First Officer of the Enterprise I think I can promise you that's not going to happen. The Kes will be denied membership.*
>
> **MAURIC:** *You have no authority to make that decision. Despite whatever games you played with the Prytt when you arrived, we still plan to take our petition directly to the Federation Council. They'll listen*
>
> **RIKER:** *They will also listen to the reports of the Captain of the Enterprise and his First Officer. And I can tell you right now the First Officer's report will go something like this. Kesprytt, a deeply troubled world with social, political, and military problems they have yet to resolve. The Kes, while a friendly and democratic people, are driven by suspicion, deviousness, and paranoia. It is the opinion of this officer they are not ready for membership.*

---

[TNG: The Hunted](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/159.htm) deals with a planet that has gone through a violent war and created (and discarded) a bunch of super-soldiers.

> Investigating a planet applying for membership into the Federation,
> the crew of the Enterprise finds a group of inhabitants who used to be
> soldiers, but now fight for their very existence.

The show ends with Picard lecturing the Prime Minister on his duties to his citizens.

> **NAYROK:** *Picard, you can't leave us like this.*
>
> **PICARD:** *I have all the information I need for our report. Your prisoner has been returned to you and you have a decision to make.
> Whether to try to force them back or welcome them home. In your own
> words, this is not our affair. We cannot interfere in the natural
> course of your society's development, and I'd say it's likely to
> develop significantly in the next several minutes. It's been an
> interesting visit. When you're ready for membership, the Federation
> will be pleased to reconsider your application. Mister Riker, four to
> beam up.*

Comment: This might be it, I could also be getting more than one episodes mixed up.

Comment: @user169303  For a moment, I was totally confused by the word "Kes." _Voyager_ memories, I guess. In other words, you're not the only one confused.